# How to use dependency injection in ASP.NET Core 2.0 for IHttpcontextAccessor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to set up a service to inject the current `HttpContext` in a class in my project so it can manage cookies.

I set up the service like this in my *Startup.cs* class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.TryAddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

How do I use this service in a C# class?

My attempt was like this:

My class to manipulate cookies, I want to inject the current `HttpContext`.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace grupoveiculos.Infraestrutura.Session
{
    public class Cookie
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

        public Cookie(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
        {
            _accessor = accessor;
        }

        public void Set(string chave, string valor, int? dataExpiracao)
        {
            CookieOptions option = new CookieOptions();

            if (dataExpiracao.HasValue)
                option.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(dataExpiracao.Value);
            else
                option.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(10);

            _accessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(chave, valor, option);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to instantiate my `Cookie` class inside the controller, it says that "there's no argument that corresponds to the required formal parameter accessor". The error is very logical, it is expecting the constructor parameter. But I expected `IHttpContextAccessor` being injected instead of me having to provide a parameter.

In my controller I tried:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("SelecionarIdioma")]
public IActionResult SelecionarIdioma(string cultura)
{
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(); // expecting the accessor parameter
    cookie.Set("idioma", cultura, 60);

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Grupo");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

There is really no need to access the `IHttpContextAccessor` just to access the response when you already have access to it within the controller action

You can create an extension method to simplify things

```
public static void AddCookie(this HttpResponse response, string chave, string valor, int? dataExpiracao) {
    CookieOptions option = new CookieOptions();

    if (dataExpiracao.HasValue)
        option.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(dataExpiracao.Value);
    else
        option.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(10);

    response.Cookies.Append(chave, valor, option);
}
```

and call it from the controller action.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("SelecionarIdioma")]
public IActionResult SelecionarIdioma(string cultura) {
    Response.AddCookie("idioma", cultura, 60); //<-- extension method.    
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Grupo");
}
```

Comment: Yes, that makes a lot of sense. I use extension methods a lot I don't know why I didn't come with this idea. The today's frameworks have so many features that you sometimes get lost.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways to do this, when you want a class to be able to use dependency injection it needs to be registered, however I believe all the controllers should be registered automatically in an MVC app.

Try injecting it into the controller instead of the Cookie directly.

```
public class MyController : Controller 
{
    private IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

    public MyController(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _accessor = accessor;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("SelecionarIdioma")]
    public IActionResult SelecionarIdioma(string cultura)
    {
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie(_accessor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes,I implemented that solution and I liked it. I may stick with it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var cookie = new Cookie(this.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>());
```

Another way would be to register the `Cookie` class itself and then inject it on the constructor.